# Magento 2.5 show out of stock products at the end of the catalog

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, category-products

I want to display out of stock products at the end of the category page of Magento 2.5.
I add this code:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php

$collection = $layer->getProductCollection(); 

$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->order('is_salable DESC');
```

But shows error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function **getSelect()** on null

Comment: You mean to say you want to show all out of stock product at end of the list page?

Comment: $collection->getSelect()->order('is_salable DESC'); add after second line

Comment: Have you try below solution?

Answer (score 0):

For Collection of product generate from `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection file.` We need to create a plugin for **load()** function. we need to set our custom condition for out of stock product to **beforeLoad()** function.

Create a **di.xml** file,

> app/code/Namespace/OutOfStock/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!--  out of stock product at end of list -->
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection">
        <plugin name="Namespace_OutOfStock::OutofstockEnd" type="Namespace\OutOfStock\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Need to override Stock.php file from `Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock class.`

Create **Toolbar.php** file, File Path, `app/code/Rbj/OutOfStock/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php`

```
<?php    

namespace Namespace\OutOfStock\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $subject
     * @param bool $printQuery
     * @param bool $logQuery
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeLoad(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $subject, $printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        $orderBy = $subject->getSelect()->getPart(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $outOfStockOrderBy = array('is_salable DESC');
        /* reset default product collection filter */
        $subject->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $subject->getSelect()->order($outOfStockOrderBy);

        return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
    }
}
```

Clear Cache and Check in front. All the Out of stock product will display at end of listing page.

[Take reference from Master!!!](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/magento-2-display-out-of-stock-products-at-the-end-of-the-list-page/)

I hope it helps!